# How to solve for the orange angles in the triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

During my preparations for the test I came across an exercise that looked something like that:(I hope it's clear enough
[image]

I tried solving it but can't manage to do it. I have tried using similar triangles, but it's not enough information for that. So, I wasn't able to find the ratio between the triangles, but writing that down makes me ask "Do I even need it?" Also, one known information that should be given is that it is just a triangle nothing else, so sides are not symmetric, the only thing known besides the lengths written is that triangle FGC and ABC are similar and that FG is the midline of the trapezoid(but I don't know which trapezoid as I can only find one - ABGF).
How to solve for the other parts of the triangle that are in the orange?

Comment: Similarity of triangles works - values are 5, 5, and 3. Don't be confused by the "distorted drawing.

Comment: It is interesting that the base value does not impact the sides - they are calculated independently of the base.

Comment: Hello, @Moti How did you calculate that?

Comment: I am guessing that the comments of @Moti are based on "FG is the midline of the trapezoid".  This seems to indicate that line segments BG and GC have the same length.

Comment: Assuming that $\angle$ CGF and $\angle$ CBA are equal, and assuming, based on the previous comments that the lengths of line segments BC and AC are known, the *law* *of* *cosines* kicks in.  Here, the length of line segment AB does become pertinent.

Comment: So, @user2661923 based on your first answer that FG is the midline of the trapezoid, may I ask you where is the trapezoid. as I don't see one, or does it mean that it is also the midline of the triangle, I don't understand. And your second comment, don't we need angle for that?

Comment: On what basis are we making these deductions? The question does not state any of what the comments say.

Comment: [1] I agree that I was taking significant license with "midline of the trapezoid".  As you indicated, without my **bald** guesswork-inference, there is insufficient information to solve the problem.  Poorly worded problems are unfortunately that not uncommon. [2] When the sides of the triangle are known, the law of cosines gives you the angles.

Comment: @MathLover Agreed.  However, absent guesswork, the problem seems to lack sufficient information.  How else can one interpret the *intent* behind the phrase "midline of the trapezoid"?  As the OP asked, *what* *trapezoid*?

Comment: Can you please write all the information that are given first as part of the question? You can then write your work / thoughts otherwise it is hard to understand what is given and what is your inference.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, that may be true but using that as midline we get correct answer and it checks out when using similarity: FC/AC = CG/CB = FG/AB = 1/2

Comment: @MathLover Sorry, rereading the question I agree, the information I have given really is pretty messy. I will write it better next time but hope you can understand it.

Comment: @user2661923 yes, _what trapezoid_ is the best way to summarize it!

Comment: The only assumption is that FG||AB. Without it the problem is not defined.

Comment: @Moti, they are perpendicular, I'm new to that too, so why couldn't that be assumed from that they are similar.

Comment: No, you also need the assumption that the line segments BG and GC are equal.

Comment: @user2661923, that wasn't given.

Comment: The segments are parallel - at least is seems in the drawing.

Comment: But, it was suggested by the "midline of the trapezoid" *nonsense* which doesn't seem to suggest any other meaning.

Comment: The middle point is the RESULT of the ratios.

Comment: What do you mean by that @Moti

Comment: Can that be assumed somehow or calculated?

Comment: It is calculated. And there are many solutions.

Comment: @Moti Could you please write one, because I can't find any! Thanks.

Comment: Assuming FG||AB, than CF/AF=CG/GB  =>  3/AF=CG/5. FG/10=3/(3+AF). Set a value for one of the unknowns and calculate the other two. Note that you need to adhere to the relation between sides of the triangle - no one side can larger than the sum of the other two.